# Tracing ancestors from 1800 back in Kentucky/Tennessee (USA)?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, tennessee, kentucky

I have a least three male relatives born between 1800 and 1810 that I cannot trace back further.

How should I continue my research?
( they all seem to be USA born Kentucky, Tennessee)

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy.SE, Susan. We are all working together to learn how to write valuable questions for the new Q&A format. Rather than pose your question as "tracing ... from 1800" I suggest you develop a separate question for each of these ancestors. This will allow you to better support your question by providing us information on that ancestor, what you have already done to try to extend that research. In other words, it allows us a better picture of the specific problem you face with that research.

Comment: @GeneJ, huh? The FAQ discourages very specific questions. Asking about researching back for individuals born around 1800 in Kentucky seems a fine question to me, one which can be answered by someone experienced in Kentucky research.

Comment: @TamuraJones. The description of real problems is encouraged. During the earlier definition phase, there were questions closed because some thought they were too localized. We addressed that during the private beta, but explaining that genealogy is a context business. See the discussions http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18/what-should-our-faq-contain and also http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/108/should-we-be-saying-what-research-we-have-done-so-far-in-questions

Comment: TamuraJones, I'm sure that GeneJ meant to relay that while the lead in question is fine, don't hesitate to put more specific information about whom you you are researching that was born between 1800 and 1810. The more you put in the more you'll get back. ;}

Answer (score 6):

We had taxes even back then and you can often track your ancestors through the county tax (or assessor) records.  Actually any county records can be very revealing.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Another strategy: Look at the census records which do list family members' names. Often families travelled to new locations in groups. It may be that the parents of one of these male relatives is living nearby or with a family member.

Ex: Stephen Brumley was born in the 18th century. His wife's father moved from Georgia to Alabama with them and is found on a later census living nearby. This helped me to go back one more generation and to make an educated guess as to the names of the family members on the 1790 census.

Answer (score -1):

Another method to research early 1800's records is to research historical books and journals on the particular counties in the particular States.

https://familysearch.org/#form=books

The LDS have a vast online library.

Comment: You can find everything on the internet, said No genealogist ever. Think link may be better kdla.ky.gov/